# redux reducer not listening for action

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, action, reducers

I have multiple actions in my app, and this one is just not listening or getting called to the next step, going to the reducer.

action file

```
    export const UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE = "UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE";
    export const updateImageState = imageData => {
      console.log(imageData)
      return {
        type: UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE,
        imageData
      }
    }
```

Note, the imageData payload is simply an object with two strings. Also, it definitely makes it to the action because it console.logs out fine.

reducer file

```
    import {
      UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE
    } from '../actions/image-action';

    const profileReducer = (state=initState, action) => {

        if (action.type === UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE) {
          console.log(action)
          return Object.assign({}, state, { 
            image: { 
              image: action.imageData.image,
              imageUrl: action.imageData.imageUrl
            } 
          })
        }

      return state;
    }

export default profileReducer;
```

Note, the console.log in the reducer even doesn't fire off. So it's not making it there for some reason, but you can see I've imported the action.

Also, I have other actions from the same file, going to the same reducer file that work. So everything seems to be connected.

store.js file

```
    import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import profileReducer from './reducers/profile-reducer';

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      user: profileReducer,
      form: formReducer
    })

    export const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

index.js file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './components/App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import {store} from './store';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store} >
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );

    reportWebVitals();
```

here's the file upload-image.jsx
this is where the action gets dispatched from

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import { updateImageState } from '../actions/image-action';
    import { API_BASE_URL } from "../config";

    class UploadIMage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
          this.state = { 
            selectedFile: null,
          }
      }

      // input select profile picture 
      singleFileChangedHandler = event => {
        this.setState({
          selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        })
      }

      singleFileUploadHandler = () => {
        const data = new FormData();
        if (this.state.selectedFile) {
          data.append('image', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
          Axios.post( `${API_BASE_URL}/user/image-upload`, data, {
            headers: {
              'accept': 'application/json',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.8',
              'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`
            }
          })
            .then((res) => {
              if (200 === res.status) {
                if ( res.data.error ) {
                  if ('LIMIT_FILE_SIZE' === res.data.errer.code) {
                    alert('Max size: 2MB')
                  } else {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    alert(res.data.error)
                  }
                } else {
                  // Success
                  let fileName = res.data;
                  // SEND TO STATE, DISPATCH ACTION ********************
                  updateImageState(fileName)
                  alert('File Uploaded');
                }
              }
            })
              .catch((err) => {
                alert(err, 'red')
              });
        } else {
          // if file not selected throw error
          alert('Please upload file')
        }
      }

      render() { 

        return ( 

          <div>
            <div className="card border-light mb-3 mt-5" style={{ boxShadow: '0 5px 10px 2px rgba(195,192,192,.5)' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                  <h3 style={{ color: '#555', marginLeft: '12px' }}>Single Image Upload</h3>
                  <p className="text-muted" style={{ marginLeft: '12px' }}>Upload Size: 250px x 250px ( Max 2MB )</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text">Please upload an image for your profile</p>
              <input type="file" onChange={this.singleFileChangedHandler}/>
              <div className="mt-5">
                  <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.singleFileUploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        
      }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return bindActionCreators({
          updateImageState
      }, dispatch)
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UploadIMage);
```

here's my github for
front end
https://github.com/Sebastian-Russo/avybe-challenge-profile
back end
https://github.com/Sebastian-Russo/profile-app-server/tree/master/profiles

Comment: Did you export your reducer?

Comment: yes, i just edited the question to show that for you, thank you.

Comment: You haven’t posted any code that shows you wiring-up the reducer into the store. Please post your code where you instantiate the store and combine/compose your reducers. Also, is there a reason you’re not using Redux Toolkit?

Comment: You’re missing the “.js” file extension in your import statement unless your Bundler specifically supports extendionless-imports?

Comment: ok, i've edited it and added more

Comment: in react, you never have to add '.js' to the end of an imported file, default.

Comment: if the console doesn't fire on your reducer, try to move it before the 'if' and check if it has the values

Comment: i did what you said and moved the console.log before the if statement. it works for other actions, but does NOT fire for this specific action posted. i wonder if that means there's an issue with where the action is being called. but i wouldn't think so, since it makes it to the action with the console.log firing off above the action

Comment: added my github page in case that would help

Comment: How/from where are you dispatching the `UPDATE_IMAGE_STATE` action?

Comment: I don't think the action is ever dispatched, you should use and look at redux devtools before asking a redux question.

Comment: i've edited and added the file where the action UPRDATE_IMAGE_STATE gets dispatched from

Answer (score 1):

So after the last couple comments about dispatching I read a little deeper into dispatching.

Everything was connected. BUT, i was calling the action directly.

WRONG (what I was doing) updateImageState()

RIGHT, (what I should have done) of this.props.updateImageState()